# Can I disable a JLabel mouse event?

Tags: java, swing

I want to disable the report_unlock. Can someone explain?

```
private void report_unlockMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           

        String password=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the security key:");

        if(password.contains("xxxxxxx")){
            reports.setEnabled(true);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login success ", "Report Unlock",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            report_unlock.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else{
            reports.setEnabled(false);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login unsuccess ", "Report Unlock",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
```

Comment: *"..JLabel mouse event.."* Don't use a label. Don't use a mouse listener. Use an action, add it to a button. Disable the action to disable the button (& make it non-focusable).

Comment: I agree that a button is more suitable for presenting something the user can click on to perform an action.  That said, you can put a flag in your class and check it in the method.  `if (disabled) { return; }`

Comment: my problem solved guys. Thank you very much.